# Как вытащить значение 456239300 из массива по ключу "pid"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
[
  {
    "pid": 456239300,
    "id": "photo5497708_456239300",
    "aid": -53,
    "owner_id": -136878126,
    "user_id": 5497708,
    "src": "https://pp.userapi.com/c841228/v841228746/5a2bf/NPdzbkgdGGE.jpg",
    "src_big": "https://pp.userapi.com/c841228/v841228746/5a2c0/qo6YCrPceGQ.jpg",
    "src_small": "https://pp.userapi.com/c841228/v841228746/5a2be/yXy1mGbw004.jpg",
    "width": 604,
    "height": 604,
    "text": "",
    "created": 1517051562
  }
]
```

Comment: `[0]['pid']` в чём проблема-то?

Comment: 100. One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid. не берет его или не правильно берет.

Comment: results['pid']   пишет TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужны значения `pid` для всех элементов списка:

```
In [40]: [d.get('pid', 'N/A') for d in lst]
Out[40]: [456239300]
```

в том случае если в каком-то из словарей будет отсутствовать ключ `pid`, вернется `'N/A'` (`Not Available`). Если вместо этого вам надо сгенерировать исключение, то лучше сделать так:

```
In [42]: [d['pid'] for d in lst]
Out[42]: [456239300]
```

Comment: 100. One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid

Comment: @СергейВикторовия, без полного error traceback ничего не понятно

Comment: я даже и не знаю, что это.   а вот что показывает отладчик               results={list}<class 'list'>: [{'pid': 456239376, ................
а когда раскрываешь. какойто 0 и уже словарем
0={dict}{'pid': 456239376,...................

Comment: @СергейВикторовия, похоже ваши реальные данные имеют другую структуру (отличную от той, что вы привели в вопросе)

Comment: [{'pid': 456239379, 'id': 'photo5497708_456239379', 'aid': -53, 'owner_id': -136878126, 'user_id': 5497708, 'src': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c834200/v834200538/97af8/aMKjC-7f2FE.jpg', 'src_big': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c834200/v834200538/97af9/YtYFWl3ul74.jpg', 'src_small': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c834200/v834200538/97af7/rypThvCSIvM.jpg', 'width': 604, 'height': 604, 'text': '', 'created': 1517065644}]

Comment: @СергейВикторовия, это список или JSON строка? И что там делают символы `;` (точка с запятой)?

Comment: это : После успешного выполнения возвращает массив, содержащий объект с загруженной фотографией.